# How to access regular Javascript function from AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular function in my controller and I want to call an external javascript function, this won't work and I'm not sure what I'm missing:

```
$scope.addSubscription = function(){
  var id = $scope.userId;
  var name = Exec.UserService.fetch(id);
  $scope.user.push({id:id, name:name});
}
```

My external javascript code looks something like this:

```
var Exec = (function() {
  "use strict";
        return {
           EntityManager: (function(){
             // some code here
           }());

           UserService: (function(){
             return {
               fetch: function(id){
                 // some code here
                 return 'something';
               },

               modify: function(id, status){
                // some code here
               }
             }; 
           }()) 
         } // end of outer return
      }()); // end of Exec
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle containing a self contained example of the problem ? (At first glance, I don't see why it wouldn't work)

Comment: This may be missing the point--I'm not sure if this file is required to be external to the Angular application--but if not, you could refactor the external Javascript code into an Angular service, then inject it into the necessary controllers.

Comment: any reason you're not just creating angular services for these services and using DI?

Comment: So I decided to create a service containing both EntityManager and UserService and it worked. But now my problem is trying to call the EntityManager.fetch function from UserService. I tried Exec.EntityManager.fetch among other things. It says it's undefined, why can't it see it?

Answer (score 4):

The reason why it doesn't work is because you need to use '`,`' instead of '`;`' to separate the key-value pair in the object. It's a syntax error and you should be able to see it in the console of your browser.

```
var Exec = (function () {
    "use strict";
    return {
        EntityManager: (function () {

        }()),  // -> should be , not ;

        UserService: (function () {
            return {
                fetch: function (id) {
                    return 'something';

                },

                modify: function (id, status) {

                }
            };
        }())
    }
}());
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GNCSd/)**</kbd>

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say about the one `EntityManager: (function () {
            // some code here
        }()),` - not the one you have commented

Comment: sorry I wasn't able to copy paste the code on here so I wrote it out, but it does have the comma instead of semicolon. In the console I'm getting and "Error: Exec is undefined".